# Solution of a function: Why is it the point where it crosses zero?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This is my first question here ever (not sure how basic this might be):

Ive been studying set theory on my own (I have a couple of books and a lot of youtube videos). I understand that a **function** is "something" that relates the elements from one set to another. Therefore, a function will "link" an $x_1$ to a given $f(x_1)$. I know there are certain functions that don't allow certain $x_n$'s to be inputted and/or some $f(x_n)$'s that will not be outputted.

I got curious regarding the graphic representation of a function. Let's say we have the function $f(x)=x^2-1$ which has the following graphic representation:

[image]

(I want to highlight where it crosses the x-axis, given it is a second order equation, it crosses it in two points. If it were $f(x)=x^2+1$ I know that the solution is in the complex realm.)

I've always been taught that the "solution" of a function is where it crosses the $x$-axis. In this case the function will have those $2$ solutions.

My question/confusion is:

What does the "solution" of a function mean, like...why is the relationship with zero important? Because if I think of it from the set theory approach, there is no "solution" (not sure about this though, I'm literally sharing my mind right now) it is just a relationship. I saw something regarding that "...it is the  of the function" I've googled that term but didn't quite found something that was clear enough for me.

> Why is the "solution" of a function where the $f(x)$ equals zero?

Thanks for reading, responses and patience :)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Many computation problems can be rewritten as asking for the root of some function, that makes roots interesting.  Of course, if $f(x)=0$ then $F(x)=1$ where $F(x)=f(x)+1$, so there's nothing magical about $0$.  Still, it's often convenient to phrase things in terms of $0$, just to standardize problems.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: In terms of sets, the set of solutions to $f(x)=0$ is the pre-image of the set $\{0\}$. More generally, the set of solutions to $f(x)=a$ is the pre-image of the set $\{a\}$.

Comment: "Solve" can be a fairly ambiguous instruction. What they likely meant was "find the roots". Which means find when f(x) = 0 ( inputs that have 0 as an output). Finding roots is a very important technique, since the roots can be used alongside other techniques to learn things about the function. You'll see some of these applications in Calculus/Pre-Calculus.

Comment: Okay, I think I may rephrase it better. Why are the roots (which is when the f(x) is zero) considered as "the solution".

Comment: I think, unfortunately you have been slightly mislead. Functions don't have "solutions". They have domains and ranges, and as sets they have elements. The Equation  x^2 = 0, has solutions - which are also the roots to the function f(x) = x^2. Thinking that functions have "solutions" is a technical error. We rewrite the function as an equation, and solve for x. The equation is what we solve, not the function. In the equation x^2 = 0, x = 0 is called a solution, because when we plug it in into the equation we get a true statment.So the solution is the numbers that make the equality  true.

Comment: I think you are reading too much into a lazy shorthand. It's so common to ask for the roots of a function that people sometimes refer to that as "solving" the function.  For instance, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%5E2-1) defaults to this reading.  But it's ambiguous terminology at best and it's always better to use clear, unambiguous  phrasing.

Comment: I see! This helps. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0,$$ we say $f(x)$ is an $n$th order polynomial; here, your function is a $2$nd order polynomial. The roots of a polynomial are the solutions (values of $x$ that satisfy equation) to the equation
$$f(x)=0.$$
Why do we care about finding the values of $x$ that solve this equation?

**Theorem: [The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra):**

> Any $n$th order polynomial $f(x)$ can be expressed as
> $$f(x)=c_0(x-c_1)(x-c_2)\dots(x-c_{n-1})(x-c_n),$$
> where (clearly) $c_1,c_2\dots c_n$ are $n$ roots, not necessarily distinct.

So given a polynomial, if we find the $n$ roots, we can easily factor the polynomial into this product, which is incredibly useful.